# How to get CPU temperature and CPU & RAM usage?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am developing an application and I do not know how I can get the CPU usage and temperature, example in a `textview`. I try with `TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE` to get temperature, but it does not work. The log file says that I do not have the sensor, but I but I can get the temperature and frequency using another application from the Play store. The code works fine, if I use other sensor like `TYPE_GYROSCOPE` or others. So, I do not know why `TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE` is not working.

Comment: A quick search in google will give you good results [Like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24280721/4123078) this one

Answer (score 0):

Because very few devices have a TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE sensor. The only devices I know have that sensor are the Galaxy S4 and Note 3.