# How to get CPU temperature in code from Android app?

Tags: android, cpu-usage, android-sensors, temperature

It appears possible to access CPU temperature from within code as evidenced by this app called "[CPU monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glgjing.stark&hl=en)" [unless it's a fake temperature]. How can I do this? There are similar questions on Stackexchange but they are old and offer no conclusive solution.

A high-level description of how this could be achieved would already be valuable!

Edit: I want this app to be able to be shared widely on the Google Play store, so no root or other special requirements would be ideal.

I did read around and found explanations on stackoverflow - but they may be outdated and are often incomplete and detail oriented rather than general.

Answer (score 1):

Android is mainly based on Linux and in Linux everything is a file. For this reason I think that [this solution taken from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48641339/11388522) could be a good initial idea.
 There are even [more Q&A about CPU temperature on stackoverflow](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=937&sxsrf=ACYBGNQlNrpROh3hMpbHDggwWxCrkqsIBQ%3A1576076759197&ei=1wXxXcPLC8TjsAfg0JGAAg&q=android%20how%20to%20get%20cpu%20temperature%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=android%20how%20to%20get%20cpu%20temperature%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3961.3961..4183...0.0..0.140.269.0j2......0....1..gws-wiz.re-RIGCOqIs&ved=0ahUKEwiDk_u6763mAhXEMewKHWBoBCAQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) and there are different way to obtain that value.

For example some solutions need that your app is a **device owner (administrator)** and others need **root** permissions.

From an **high-level description** Android usea files to save information about hardware and an app has to read those files in order to obtain informations.

Comment: The file system trick works, but it varies from device to device. I'm curious how the app developers of the above-mentioned app managed to abstract the problem. I'll try decompiling the app.