# How can I use hardwarepropertiesmanager(android) in android api 30, android 11

Tags: java, android, android-11, android-api-30

Now I'm trying to run

```
HardwarePropertiesManager hardwarePropertiesManager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(HardwarePropertiesManager.class);
        hardwarePropertiesManager.getDeviceTemperatures(HardwarePropertiesManager.DEVICE_TEMPERATURE_CPU, HardwarePropertiesManager.TEMPERATURE_CURRENT);
```

to check cpu usage and temperature..

but, the exception occurred, which is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.___/com.example.___.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.SecurityException: The caller is neither a device 
owner, nor holding the DEVICE_POWER permission, nor the current 
VrListener.
```

is there any method to check cpu temperature and cpu usage(memory, core)??

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation mentions HardwarePropertiesManager is available for applications which are device owners - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HardwarePropertiesManager

You can try reading the data from file

> sys/class/hwmon/hwmonX/temp1_input

There are some changes based on vendors. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59306562 for comprehensive list.